# Function returns an empty list when called in FutureBuilder but a list of values when called independently

Tags: flutter, dart

I developed an app, generated an apk then tested it on my phone. And it was working without any problem. Now after a few days, I came back to my code to finalize it and release an app.
But for no obvious reason it is throwing this error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CustomTextButtonList(dirty):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

Now I understand what this error means but don't know why it's throwing it. i.e
I have passed `etea.scrapeResults(load_more: loadMore)` to FutureBuilder and it is returning an empty list to the future which results in an error when an indexing operation is performed on an empty list. But the thing is when I call `etea.scrapeResults(load_more: loadMore)` as an indepent function then it returns a List of values and not an empty list.
What could be the problem?

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var etea = EteaResult();
  var resultList = [];
  bool loadMore = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(...
```

```
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if (notification is LoadMoreNotification) {
          setState(() {
            loadMore = true;
          });
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: etea.scrapeResults(load_more: loadMore),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            resultList.addAll(snapshot.data as List);
            return Expanded(child: CustomTextButtonList(resultList));
          } else {
            return Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: customTheme.colors.accentColor),
              ),
            );
```

Checked multiple times this `etea.scrapeResults(load_more: loadMore)` function returns a list of values and not an empty list, when I call it independently but when I prints `snapshot.data` in FutureBuilder then it print an empty list.
It was not so the last time I checked it? Why I am getting an empty list?

Comment: Did you forget to call `setState` on calling `resultList.addAll`?

Comment: No, no need to call setState because the NotificationListener manages that automatically.

Comment: Actually, I am getting an empty shapshot in future, and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Run from the command line:

`flutter clean`

then

`flutter pub get`

Restarted VS-Code and closed all of its other instances. Then restarted the OS. And the error was gone.